# Declaring tuple without initializing in C#

Tags: c#, tuples

I want to use `Tuple`s in my code dynamically and have to assign the values to tuple *according* to the `if` statement. I have the following code:

```
if(check != null)
  var scoreTmpTuple = new Tuple<Guid, string, double>(
    (Guid)row["sampleGuid"],
     Convert.ToString(row["sampleName"]), 
     Convert.ToDouble(row["sampleScore"]));
else
  var scoreTmpTuple = new Tuple<Guid, string, double>(
    (Guid)row["exampleGuid"],
     Convert.ToString(row["exampleName"]), 
     Convert.ToDouble(row["exampleScore"]));
```

In the code, the tuple is declared *inside* the `if` and `else` statements. I want to declare that *outside* and initialize the tuple accordingly.

Comment: That might work but i had the scope issue for the tuple .. because alot of things are being done after initializing and i want the same tuple for that .

Comment: Above c#4, instead of Tuple, you could use dynamic datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *ternary operator* and push ramification within tuple creation:

```
  var scoreTmpTuple = Tuple.Create(
                (Guid)row[check != null ? "sampleGuid" : "exampleGuid"],
     Convert.ToString(row[check != null ? "sampleName" : "exampleName"]),
     Convert.ToDouble(row[check != null ? "sampleScore" : "exampleScore"])
  );
```

Or even (if we actually should switch between `"sample"` and `"example"` prefixes):

```
  string prefix = check != null 
    ? "sample"
    : "example";

  var scoreTmpTuple = Tuple.Create(
                (Guid)row[$"{prefix}Guid"],
     Convert.ToString(row[$"{prefix}Name"]),
     Convert.ToDouble(row[$"{prefix}Score"])
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the type explicity instead of using var:

```
Tuple<Guid, string, double> scoreTmpTuple;

if (check != null)
    scoreTmpTuple = Tuple.Create<Guid, string, double>(Guid.NewGuid(), "hello", 3.14);
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare the tuple before the if statement.

```
Tuple<Guid, string, double> scoreTmpTuple;

if(check != null)
   scoreTmpTuple = new Tuple<Guid, string, double>((Guid)row["sampleGuid"],Convert.ToString(row["sampleName"]), Convert.ToDouble(row["sampleScore"]));

else
   scoreTmpTuple = new Tuple<Guid, string, double>((Guid)row["exampleGuid"],Convert.ToString(row["exampleName"]), Convert.ToDouble(row["exampleScore"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
bool isChecked = check != null;

var scoreTmpTuple = new Tuple<Guid, string, double>(
                      isChecked ? (Guid)row["sampleGuid"] : (Guid)row["exampleGuid"],
                      isChecked ? Convert.ToString(row["sampleName"]) : Convert.ToString(row["exampleName"]), 
                      isChecked ? Convert.ToDouble(row["sampleScore"]) : Convert.ToDouble(row["exampleScore"]));
```

Comment: `bool isChecked = check != null;` is a shorter code